# Lenovo Yoga Tab 3 10" (YT3-X50) factory image, OTA update or backup needed

Tags: ota-update, factory-image, lenovo-yoga

I was playing around with some modifications to my rooted Yoga Tab 3, and I messed up - the tablet wouldn't boot anymore, even after a factory reset. I could still boot into recovery, so I was not too worried until I realized that I can't just download a factory image or an OTA update for my tablet in order to restore everything.

In desperation, I tried flashing the update image for YT3_850F, which was available online. This made the tablet boot again (I can hear the sound and I can see it through ADB), but without anything being displayed on the screen, which is strange, since both tablets seem to share the same graphics card (Qualcomm Adreno 304).

I think my only remaining option is to locate a factory image, or an OTA update for my tablet and flash it in recovery. Does anyone know where I can get an image for YT3-X50?

Or maybe someone with a rooted tablet could do me and the rest of the Internet a huge favour and make a backup image of their tablet available?

Are there any other recovery options that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm a Chinese, I could browse Chinese sites (including Lenovo's own) and grab what I can get. Here's something I dug up with a wee bit of search.

- [Factory images](http://ask.lenovomobile.com/?q-609280.html) (page in Chinese). Available for both F (WiFi) and M (cellular) variants. Click any link with "链接跳转" before them to go to the download landing page, then click what's behind "下载地址" for the actual download site (Baidu Cloud). It does seem to require Baidu Cloud client to be installed, so if you can't download it yourself, give me a heads-up and I'll see if I can host it on my own AFH. The extraction password (if there's any) is "ask.lenovomobile.com".
- [Flashing tutorial](http://ask.lenovomobile.com/?q-609253.html) (page in Chinese). Requires an SD card with >4GB free space, and a >50% charged battery. Rename the extracted firmware package (something like `YT3-X50F_USR_S000015_1509171725_Q1241_PRC_CN_otafull_factory_update.zip`) to `* factory_update.zip` (as the page says, "*" stands for any amount of characters - I don't know what that means exactly so I'll just leave the translation here). Insert the card into the device when it's powered off, then hold POWER and VOL+ for ~3 secs until it vibrates and boots. The devices should automatically do a factory reset and update from the zip, then reboot subsequently.
- Also refer to this [starter thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/thinkpad-tablet/general/yoga-tab-3-starter-thread-t3247657) for general info.

Comment: Thanks so much, Andy! This looks like the right firmware. I am having trouble downloading it though, since it requires registration and a client, which will take even more work to set up on Linux. If it's not too much trouble for you, could you grab the WiFi firmware and post it somewhere I can easily download it from? Much appreciated.

Comment: Done - [AndroidFileHost](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=529152257862686844).

Comment: Thanks again! My tablet is now restored from that image.

Comment: For anyone who needs the firmware for the M variant... [AndroidFileHost](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=673368273298925858) (in RAR format, extraction password above)